# Docker Swarm accepting containers as workers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a  vm which is running 5 docker containers.  The main vm server is the manager of the swarm.  I need to add the five containers to the swarm so that they can be managed.  NOTE:  Mole:  Sorry, Bub.  Things are done different in the States vs uk.

Answer (score 0):

Docker swarm does not directly manage containers.

First, you create a service, or a stack - which is a collection of services.

`docker service create --name nginx nginx`

Services are implicitly replicated, and will be scheduled on swarm nodes. Each replication instance is called a task. You can get a list of the tasks associated with a service:

```sh
% docker service ps --no-trunc nginx
ID                          NAME      IMAGE                      NODE    DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE            ERROR     PORTS
mnhvyw9bz5nkup42scnkd0bnh   nginx.1   nginx:latest@sha256:....   node1   Running         Running 16 seconds ago
```

Tasks have a desired state and a current state - they can be creating, running, stopped etc. A task that is created or running will be associated with a container on a node, which will be shown in the ps list, and the containers name will be the task name and task ID.

```sh
% docker inspect mnhvy --format {{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}
9cab5bb381b5ee5519f534393a8bd9014e4263c0afd6bb85f81a597728aa3f39
```

Now, you can access one of the containers associated with the service using the container id (discovered by inspecting the task) or the container name (append the name and id from the ps list to get `nginx.1.mnhvyw9bz5nkup42scnkd0bnh`)

```sh
docker -H ssh://node1 exec -it 9cab5 /bin/sh 
#
```

Comment: I will give it a try...

Comment: As an additional note, you'll have worker nodes and manager nodes. You can run the command to start services (or deploy stacks) only on manager nodes and they will manage workers as appropriate.